# reading in utf-8 file (javascript XMLHttpRequest) gives bad european characters

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, xmlhttprequest

can anyone help? I have small procedure to read in an UTF-8 file with javascript using XMLHttpRequest.. this file has european characters like miércoles sábado etc.. Notice the accents..

But when being read in .. the characters are all messed up.. I have checked the file and it is perfect.. it must be the procedure for reading in..

heres an example i have file that contains, the file is perfect, it happens to be javascript but it doesn't matter.. any UTF-8 encoding file with special characters gives me the same issue

this.weekDays = new Array("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo");

but when returned and read by the procedure below it is like this (notice the funny characters in sabado and miercoles)

this.weekDays = new Array("Lunes", "Martes", "MiÃ©rcoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "SÃ¡bado", "Domingo");

Here is my procedure - its very small...

```
var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open("GET", path, false);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', contentType)

if (request.overrideMimeType) request.overrideMimeType(contentType);

try { request.send(null); }
catch (e) { return null; }
if (request.status == 500 || request.status == 404 || request.status == 2 || (request.status == 0 && request.responseText == '')) return null;

//PROBLEM HERE is with european charcters that are read in

print(request.responseText);


return request.responseText;
```

Comment: are you sure the file is in UTF-8? Did you set your text editor to save it with that encoding explicitly?
Setting the request to UTF-8 is irrelvant, is the answer really in UTF-8 and the corresponding header set in the response?

Comment: thgis is old but for anyone stumbling on this, use the *.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=utf8');* method of the xmlhttprequest object from [MDN Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Seems that this answer, although accepted, is suboptimal, so for anyone coming here with a similar problem, check out [Ricardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798825/34065)

I think you have to use a different way to print the characters, for example, see the code at the end of [this discussion](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-4588.html):

```
<script>
  function getUnicode(num) {
    num = num.toString(16);
    if (num.length < 3) {
      for ( var i = num.length; i < 4; i++) {
        num = '0' + num;
      }
    }
    return ( "&#" + num + ";" );
  }

  for ( var i = 0; i < 65355; i++) {
    document.write(getUnicode(i));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 27):

Probably your file is not in UTF-8 then try this from javascript:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", path, false);
request.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

Comment: I'm sure my file is UTF-8 encoded, but the server didn't return this charset header, so this solved the problem.

Comment: @Dinei if this snippet is working for you that means your output is not in UTF8. Some server providers could make modify your output. I suggest to try it in postman and check the headers.

Comment: I have a `.json` file which is UTF-8 encoded, but for some reason it is being served with `Content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1` header. Using `overrideMimeType` with `charset=UTF-8` solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue and I fixed in this way.

If you serve the js file containing the spanish days as UTF-8 and the if is NOT saved as UTF-8 it WONT work.

Save the file in your IDE as UTF-8  (ie. eclipse default for js files will be cp1252) and also serve it as UTF-8 char encoding.

If your app is java, do a filter with this code:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

have a good one

Comment: `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue,I have solved in this way,

While In Get request, we are sending data through url
So i decoded the url and get requested parameter through string operations

Consider if you are sending url like this,
var ur1="getSubjectList.jsp";
ur1 +="?subjectlist=" +str+"&examId="+examId;

xmlHttp.open("GET", ur1, true);
 xmlHttp.send(null);

In getSubjectList.jsp, Use this--
String decodedParams= URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(),"utf-8" );

String params[]=decodedParams.split("&");

```
     String subjectlist[]=params[0].split("=");
     String examId[] = params[1].split("=");
     String center = subjectlist[1];
    String exam = examId[1];
```

In this way,You can get the requested values

Comment: Sorry, but this question is about javascript, not java.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I had an AJAX request to the PHP server to check for duplicate names in the database.

When I sent the AJAX request through the GET method, the URL was encoded, so my variable got value on the server like `%D0%A6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2`.

To solve this I just used the `urldecode` function: [PHP urldecode(string $string)].[1]
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

**So, my JS function looks like this:**

```
function checkName(e) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var responseJSON = JSON.parse(this.response);

            /*Do what you want with result here*/
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, 
        + e.target.value //input text
    , true);
    
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**and my PHP code looks like this:**

```
public function nameCheck($name){
    try{
        $name = urldecode($name);
        /*...do what you want with your variable after decoding...*/
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        /*...*/
    }

}
```

I hope this helps, for everyone who has a project with PHP.

**Cheers and happy coding!**