# Read lines from file in array

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have file main.log something like :

```
10-01-1970 01:42:52 Bus_Power device 9 up
10-01-1970 01:42:52 External_Power device 9 up
10-01-1970 01:42:57 Bus_Power device 1 down
10-01-1970 01:42:57 Bus_Power device 2 down
```

Every row is one data. How to parse this in array of rows using Dojo or plain JavaScript ?

for example :

```
['10-01-1970 01:42:52 Bus_Power device 9 up','10-01-1970 01:42:52 External_Power device 9 up']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the file into a string (say 'text'), then you can do:

```
var lines = text.split("\n");
```

Check if your file on the server terminates lines with just one line-feed (UNIX-style) or a CR-LF pair (Windows-style).

How do you get the file into a string in the first place?  You can use `dojo.xhrGet(...)`.  Look it up in the Dojo docs.

Answer (score 4):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'main.log', false);
xhr.send(null);

var log = xhr.responseText.split('\n');

// `log` is the array of logs you want
```

*Note: Done synchronously, for simplicity, as no details were given about application of this functionality.*

Comment: Note for OP: dojo will have a nice AJAX component which you should use instead to benefit from the library.

Comment: +1 Maybe use `xhr.responseText.split( /\r?\n/ );` in stead? Or is that unnecessary? (I'm not sure actually).

Answer (score 1):

Say you're reading a text/log file, the following codes are modified from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021086/reading-in-utf-8-file-javascript-xmlhttprequest-gives-bad-european-characters) of stackflow.com,

```
var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
request.open("GET", 'test.log', false);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', contentType);

if (request.overrideMimeType) request.overrideMimeType(contentType);

// exception handling
try { request.send(null); } catch (e) { return null; }
if (request.status == 500 || request.status == 404 || request.status == 2 || (request.status == 0 && request.responseText == '')) return null;

lines = request.responseText.split('\n')
for( var i in lines ) {
    console.log(lines[i]);
}
```

Problems may caused by encoding/decoding issue, so we may need exception handing as well. For more information about XMLHttpRequest, pls visit [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/).