# XMLHttpRequest returns wrongly encoded characters

Tags: javascript, pdf, utf-8, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest

I use XMLHttpRequest to read the PDF document
http://www.virtualmechanics.com/support/tutorials-spinner/Simple2.pdf

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ
[...]
```

and print its content out to console:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
      console.log('âãÏÓ');
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.virtualmechanics.com/support/tutorials-spinner/Simple2.pdf', true);
xhr.send();
```

However, the console says

```
%PDF-1.3
%����
[...]
âãÏÓ
```

(The last line is from the reference `console.log` above to verify that the console can actually display those characters.)
Apparently, the characters are wrongly encoded at some point. What's going wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Probably your console font simply does not have glyphs for `âãÏÓ`...

Comment: @mkl Yes, it has. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Arg, I did not see immediately, you use `XMLHttpRequest.responseText`. This property already tries to interpret the response as text and seems to fail. PDF files are not text files and, therefore, shall not be treated as such.  You may want to try working with `XMLHttpRequest.response` instead, also cf. the MDN [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest's default response type is `text`, but here one is actually dealing with binary data. [Eric Bidelman](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) describes how to work with it.

The solution to the problem is to read the data as a `Blob`, then to extract the data from the blob and plug it into `hash.update(..., 'binary')`:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', details.url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (this.status === 200) {
    var a = new FileReader();
    a.readAsBinaryString(this.response);
    a.onloadend = function() {
      var hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
      hash.update(a.result, 'binary');
      console.log(hash.digest('hex'));
    };
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

The MIME type of your file might not be UTF-8. Try overriding it as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798825/1932141) and depicted below:

```
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.virtualmechanics.com/support/tutorials-spinner/Simple2.pdf', true);
xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1');
xhr.send();
```