# Loading a PDF document on all browsers from another domain that requires authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, client-server, cross-domain

I am working on a server+client which use authentication. The client logs in using a username/password by hitting a certain endpoint on the server, and obtaining an authorization token. All subsequent server calls use the token to authenticate with the server. This allows the two to live in different domains.

The issue I'm having is that I need to show a PDF document in the user's browser. The server won't give you the PDF unless you include a valid token in an HTTP request header. For that reason, I can't just link the user to a server page, I have to AJAX it in with the correct headers and somehow display (or download if all else fails) the PDF document. Likewise, I can't use `<embed>` or similar solutions for the same reason: I can't get my own HTTP headers into those requests.

I also tried [data URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), as in an `<a>` whose `href` is `data:application/pdf;base64,etc`, but those don't work in IE or Edge, apparently for security reasons (?).

I also looked into [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html), which is a sub-optimal solution to begin with (I'd rather show the PDF, not download it), and it doesn't support IE 9 either. So far, this is the most compatible solution because it supports Edge.

Is there a way to AJAX the authorization-protected PDF data and reliably show it in all modern browsers, including Edge?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29917030/xmlhttprequest-returns-wrongly-encoded-characters/29922450#29922450 shows a direction you could take using XHR

Comment: Well that describes how to download it correctly, but I'm trying to either show it to the user or allow the user to save it to a file.