# XML feed return question mark symbols in text

Tags: javascript, xml

I try to fetch an external XML feed. The XML has encoding iso-8859-1

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText)    
      }
    }

  xhr.send();
```

When I look in the xml feed directly, it looks like it should with correct letters. But the reponseText will have a lot of question mark symbols in the text.
Here is an example of some text where it should be Millésimé

[image]

How can this be fixed? I have tried to add `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"')` but without any effect

I have also tried using `iconv` without any luck

Comment: "I have tried to add xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset="utf-8"')" — The `Content-Type` **request** header describes the type of content you are **sending**, not recieving.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I will remove it. Do you have an idea why it is not working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21798825/19068 looks like the most promising answer on the duplicate.